# Hand cursor in question feed text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, feed

On the question feed popup (you can find the link on every non closed question on the right side panel) there is a hand cursor over description text:

> [image: hand]

But clicking on the text does nothing. Seems that cursor should be an ordinary arrow.